# Arbitrary calculation for arbitrary member variable

Tags: c#, lambda

Consider this simple example:

```
class Foo
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public List<Foo> foos; // This complicates matters a bit
}
```

Now I want to calculate the sum/min/max/mean etc of any of the members - including the `Foo` children. I want to make a general function for this so I don't have to duplicate code.

I imagine a function call like this:

```
double sum = Calculate<double>(someFoo, sum => (f => f.a));
int count = Calculate<int>(someFoo, count => (f => 1 + foo.Length));
```

Hence, **an arbitrary operation for an arbitrary member** of `Foo`. Can this be done in C# 4.0? E.g. using [Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a helper function that gives you all `Foo`s:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> SelfAndDescendants
{
  get
  {
    yield return this;
    foreach(var child in foos)
      foreach(var descendant in SelfAndDescendants(child)
        yield return descendant;
  }
}
```

Then you can simply use normal LINQ to do your aggregation: `root.SelfAndDescendents.Sum(f=>f.a)`

---

If you want to push reusability even further, you can use a generic helper function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirstTopDownTraversal(T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children)
{
    Stack<T> s=new Stack<T>();
    s.Push(root);
    while(s.Count>0)
    {
      T current = s.Pop();
      yield return current;
      foreach(var child in children(current))
        s.Push(child);
    }
}
```

and then implement `SelfAndDescendats` as `return DepthFirstTopDownTraversal(this, f=>f.foos);`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this. Your syntax is a bit off though. It would look like this:

```
double sum = Calculate<double>(someFoo, f => f.a);
int count = Calculate<int>(someFoo, f => 1 + f.Length);
```

The method would look like this:

```
public T Calculate<T>(Foo foo, Func<Foo, T> calculator)
{
    return calculator(foo);
}
```

However, all of this doesn't really make sense for one instance of `Foo`. More likely, `someFoo` should really be `someFoos`, i.e. multiple objects. Furthermore, I guess you want to be able to specify the aggregate method, too.
That would change `Calculate` to this:

```
public T Calculate<T>(IEnumerable<Foo> foo, Func<Foo, T> calculator,
                      Func<IEnumerable<T>, T> aggregate)
{
    return aggregate(foo.Select(calculator));
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Foo> someFoos = ...;
var sum = Calculate(someFoos, x => x.a, Enumerable.Sum)
var count = Calculate(someFoos, x => 1 + x.Length, Enumerable.Count)
```

To make it all recursive, the easiest way is to have a method that returns a `Foo` object and all its children as a flat list:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Flatten(Foo foo)
{
    yield return foo;
    foreach(var child in foo.Children.SelectMany(Flatten))
        yield return child;
}
```

Using this method in `Calculate` would result in this:

```
public T Calculate<T>(IEnumerable<Foo> foo, Func<Foo, T> calculator,
                      Func<IEnumerable<T>, T> aggregate)
{
    return aggregate(Flatten(foo).Select(calculator));
}
```

---

Having said and written all this, I have to ask: Why don't you just use normal LINQ?

```
Flatten(foo).Select(f => f.a).Sum();
Flatten(foo).Select(f => 1 + f.Length).Count();
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. What would the `Calculate` function look like? (I believe two actions are needed.)

Comment: @l33t: Please see update. I guess that's what you really meant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. According to the way you want to call the `Calculate` method, you can define it as follows:

```
private T Calculate<T>(Foo foo, Func<Foo, Func<Foo, T>> func) {
    //do something here...
}
```

**Edit:** Perhaps it doesn't make too much sense, so it would be useful if you can provide us an example of an expected input/output.